# Как создать объект NSDictionary в своем классе?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Мне необходимо в своем классе создать объект NSDictionary и инициализировать его, чтобы потои можно было работать с ним из разных методов. Пытаюсь это делать так:

```
@interface Zahl : NSObject{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText, *outText;
    NSDictionary *myLibrary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"neun",   @"9", nil];
}
@end
```

Xcode выдает ошибку: "Expected ';' at end of declaration list"
Ничего не пойму, что это значит? Точка с запятой ведь стоит в конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не получится, в obj-c четко отделены объявления и реализации, проще всего вам будет в @interface создать свойство (ivar тоже можно, но лучше все-таки свойство, встречается в каком-то из относительно недавних гидов и была интересная тема на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236799/should-i-declare-variables-in-interface-or-using-property-in-objective-c-arc)):

```
@interface Zahl : NSObject{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText, *outText;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *myLibrary1;
@end
```

А в конструкторе уже определить ваш словарь (только вме):

```
-(instancetype) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
       self.myLibrary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"neun",   @"9", nil]; 
    }
    return self;

}
```

Comment: > проще всего вам будет в @interface создать свойство (ivar тоже можно, но лучше все-таки свойство

Я думаю в контексте этого вопроса лучше объяснить ТС, как сделать то, что он хочет в точности, а отношения между ivars и properties - это уже отдельная тема, с которой он столкнётся в своё время.

Answer (score 2):

Внутри скобок `{}` в `@interface Class : NSObject {}` вы просто **объявляете** переменные (они называются `instance vars` или `ivars`), их **инициализацию** вы делаете уже внутри @implementation для своего класса - обычно она делается в блоке инициализации самого класса. Вот процедура инициализации класса Zahl и инициализации его переменной _myLibrary:

```
@interface Zahl : NSObject{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *inputText, *outText;
    NSDictionary *_myLibrary1;
}
@end

@implementation Zahl
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _myLibrary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"neun",   @"9", nil]
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)someMethod {
    // Делаете что-нибудь с _myLibrary1
}

@end
```

Пара советов:

1. Вы объявляете myLibrary1 как instance var (внутри {}) - instance var обычно называют, добавляя символ `_`.
2. Не используйте русских слов в своём коде. Кажется, вы используете Зал (Zahl)? Если да, то напишите лучше Hall, например.

Comment: Спасибо! А Zahl - это у меня немецкое слово "Число".

Comment: Самого главного вы не написали, что в @interface переменные не инициализируются. Этот блок служит только для объявления переменных.

Comment: Только что обновил ответ)) Вы одновременно написали.

Comment: > Спасибо! А Zahl - это у меня немецкое слово "Число".

Ну тогда хорошо. Главное, что вы знаете, что делаете. Просто знайте, что в целом лучше избегать всего не-английского в названиях.